# How to encode the real time audio?

Tags: java, audio, ogg, oggvorbis

I am on creating voice report. The user has to submit his voice report and it should simultaneously encode the audio data using Vorbis encoder. Its working fine but 
encoding will start after the recording is over.

But I should have to employ the Vorbis encoder on the fly. Please share any sample code it would be much helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be more specific about how you record the audio. Do you just get the wav file or you get chunks of data? If latter, why don't you just feed it to the encoder in real time?

Comment: i am getting the chunks of data

Comment: Then, as I said before, just feed it to the encoder. If vorbis encoder that you use does not support that (the development stopped in 2007) then consider jspeex. It gives much better quality and compression rates for speech.